# Problema em consultas N : N

Tags: mysql, sql

Gostaria de saber porque não consigo buscar uma consulta em tabelas que possuem o relacionamento N para N. Preciso buscar o nome do produto, o nome do seu fabricante, o nome e e-mail dos seus fornecedores, só que o My Sql retorna 'unknown column fornecedor.nome in field list', a questão é que eu não sei aonde está o erro. Observação : o erro esta no segundo JOIN, mas eu não sei porque, já que eu tenho duas chaves estrangeiras. Logo o My Sql deveria retornar os dados do fornecedor. Aqui estão todas as tabelas e o comando de consulta que eu criei para esse problema:

```
create table fabricante(
idFabricante int primary key auto_increment,
nome VARCHAR(45) not null
);

create table produto(
idProduto int primary key auto_increment,
idClassificacao int,
idFabricante int,
nome varchar(45) not null,
descricao varchar(100),
valor_Venda FLOAT not null,
quantidade int default '0'
);

create table fornecedor(
cnpj int primary key, 
nome varchar(45) not null,
ie varchar(15) unique not null,
endereco varchar(45),
bairro varchar(30),
cidade varchar(30),
estado varchar(2) default 'SP',
cep varchar(8),
telefone varchar(8) unique,
email varchar(50) unique
);

create table produto_has_fornecedor(
idProduto int,
cnpj int,
foreign key(idProduto) references produto(idProduto),
foreign key(cnpj) references fornecedor(cnpj)
);

SELECT produto.nome AS 'Produto', fabricante.nome AS 'Fabricante', fornecedor.nome, fornecedor.email
FROM produto
JOIN fabricante
ON fabricante.idFabricante = produto.idFabricante
JOIN produto_has_fornecedor
ON produto_has_fornecedor.cnpj = fornecedor.cnpj;
```

Comment: Não faltou fazer um JOIN com a tabela fornecedor em sua query? Creio que produto_has_fornecedor deva ter um JOIN com a tabelas produto e outro com fornecedor.

Comment: Eu fiz com a de fornecedor, mas não estou conseguindo colocar outro JOIN embaixo

Answer (score 0):

É só acrescentar a tabela com a condição de junção adequada:

```
SELECT produto.nome AS 'Produto', fabricante.nome AS 'Fabricante', fornecedor.nome, fornecedor.email
FROM produto
JOIN fabricante
ON fabricante.idFabricante = produto.idFabricante
JOIN produto_has_fornecedor
ON produto_has_fornecedor.idProduto = produto.idProduto
JOIN fornecedor
ON produto_has_fornecedor.cnpj = fornecedor.cnpj;
```